# Need to pin all flyway updates to 1 schema_version table in a specified schema

Tags: flyway

We want to be able to pin all sql executions to a particular schema_version table in schema A. We need this so that we can run sqls as a sysdba and flyway always references A.schema_version to validate checksums and update result of SQL runs. We tried by adding the following settings:

flyway.schemas=A
flyway.table=schema_version

However we find that if we run info as user B then flyway is not able to show it can read A.schema_version. What are we missing?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution. Schemas is case sensitive as specified in the flyway docs. We needed to reference flyway.schemas= where schema_name is in caps